# Generate Textview dynamically based on JSON response

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

Hi I'm getting a JSON response in the below format, I have parsed the response and getting the values in my application. I need to show the dashboard in the application and I want them as Individual rows and to be displayed in the textviews where they are dynamic.

[image: Dashboard]

This is what I have tried.

```
  public void onSuccess(String response) {

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            pgDialog.hide();
            try {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);

                    String name = obj.getString("rider_name");
                    String time = obj.getString("ride_time");
                    String avg = obj.getString("ride_distance");

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





[{"id":"1","rider_name":"AAAA","ride_distance":"0","ride_time":"00:00:08"},{"id":"2","rider_name":"BBBB","ride_distance":"0","ride_time":"00:00:39"},{"id":"3","rider_name":"CCCC","ride_distance":"0","ride_time":"00:00:09"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you're trying to display a list of data containing 3 fields retrieved from the JSON. You could set a RecyclerView, which it's corresponding Adapter and ViewHolder to display those 3 fields.
I must ask, is there any reason why you're creating a GSON instance? You seem to be handling JSON manually.
This is android's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) for the use of lists, and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) there's a tutorial which uses a RecyclerView to display a row with 3 TextViews, just like you are trying to do.

Comment: I need to use only textviews as per my requirement.

Comment: OK, if that's the case you could use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and programmatically inflate a view containing your three TextViews, and use LinearLayout's addView to add them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a view for the row design ( which will contain the text view ) then use it in a recycleview or listview.
Your JSONArray arr will be reflected as an Array then implement it in the list.

 The logic will be as an ArrayList of Rrider class you will fill it in your code then add it to the list adapter

**Check out these tutorial:**
Recycler View example : http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/
ListView example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm